# How to convert BufferedImage(RGB) to BufferedImage(ARGB or RGBA)?

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage

I'm trying to convert the RGB image produced by the Robot.createScreenCapture function to ARGB image. My goal is to set transparency when the pixel haven't changed between two images but I get black color. As shown in the below image.

For example BufferedImage as created as below:

```
 BufferedImage currImage = robot.createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(x, y, width,height));
```

The following function is intended to create ARGB pixel.

```
private BufferedImage bufferedImagesEqual(BufferedImage prevImage,
        BufferedImage currImage) {
    boolean changed = false;
    BufferedImage imagePart = new BufferedImage(currImage.getWidth(), currImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    if (prevImage.getWidth() == currImage.getWidth()
            && prevImage.getHeight() == currImage.getHeight()) {

        for (int x = 0; x < currImage.getWidth(); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < prevImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                 int argb =  currImage.getRGB(x, y);
                if (prevImage.getRGB(x, y) != currImage.getRGB(x, y)){
                //  return false;
                    //  currImage.setRGB(x, y, 0);
                    if(!changed){
                        changed = true;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    imagePart.setRGB(x, y, 0xff000000);
                }
            }
        }
    } else {
        return imagePart;
    }
    if(changed){
        return imagePart;
    }else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this return before and after the setRGB call ?  

Color pixel = new Color(imagePart.getRGB(x, y), true);
pixel.getAlpha()

Comment: Try using `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).getRGB()` instead of `0xff000000` as it removes the ambiguity

Comment: `0xff000000` is opaque black... What you want is `0x0` (or `0x00000000` if you like to be verbose), which is 100% transparent black (or, rather 0 opacity black). Or do as @MadProgrammer says, if in doubt. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the before and after images...

[image: Before] [image: After]

By using `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)` instead of `0xff000000` (and painting SOMETHING when the pixels as equal), I get

[image: Output]

Using...

```
import java.awt.AlphaComposite;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class ConvertBuffer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            BufferedImage before = ImageIO.read(new File("/Before.jpg"));
            BufferedImage after = ImageIO.read(new File("/After.jpg"));

            BufferedImage result = bufferedImagesEqual(before, after);

            JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(result));
            label.setOpaque(true);
            label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, label);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static BufferedImage bufferedImagesEqual(BufferedImage prevImage,
                    BufferedImage currImage) {
        boolean changed = false;
        BufferedImage imagePart = new BufferedImage(currImage.getWidth(), currImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        if (prevImage.getWidth() == currImage.getWidth()
                        && prevImage.getHeight() == currImage.getHeight()) {

            for (int x = 0; x < currImage.getWidth(); x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < prevImage.getHeight(); y++) {
                    if (prevImage.getRGB(x, y) != currImage.getRGB(x, y)) {
                //  return false;
                        //  currImage.setRGB(x, y, 0);
                        if (!changed) {
                            changed = true;
                        }
                        imagePart.setRGB(x, y, currImage.getRGB(x, y));
                    } else {
                        imagePart.setRGB(x, y, new Color(0, 0, 0, 0).getRGB());
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            return imagePart;
        }
        if (changed) {
            return imagePart;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

So, unless you have an example image to play with, this is the best we can do...

Comment: What does it look like with the original 0xff000000 ?

Comment: @Dylan It looks black

Comment: `new Color(0, 0, 0, 0)` removes the ambiguity, theres no possible way to confuse the intentions of that call.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I don't see transparency in your result. Since red rectangle block is changed in before and after images, only that part need to be shown and everything else(means background) should be transparent. How this can be achieved?

Comment: I think @MadProgrammer has achieved the transparency, the Blue is from the Button background underneath the transparent bits, not the image created in bufferedImagesEqual.

Comment: @Dylan I use the blue background to highlight the difference, the blue comes from the labels background, so anything not transparent will not be blue